# Ubuntu isn't an option on startup, Windows 10 automatically loads

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I know that there are tons of questions related to this, yet none of them have seemed to solve my issue. I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, but Windows 10 automatically loads and I have no choice on the restart after installation. Ubuntu **is** installed, and I partitioned the hard drive during the installation process.

This is the [guide](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html) I followed, except I used a CD instead of a USB.

I switched the boot order according to the guide ("Change The Boot Order So That Ubuntu Can Boot") but it apparently doesn't save. Ubuntu doesn't show up on the F2 nor F12 boot menus. The only thing that shows up on those is the Windows Bootloader.

I'm running Windows 10 64-bit on an Acer Aspire E5-575G. I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04.1 64-bit.

This is my partitions screen

[image: Screenshot]

When I first downloaded Ubuntu, I didn't realize it came with Grub so I downloaded it manually. Could this be messing with the bootloader?

Comment: It looks like you didn't properly set up the installation media - i.e. your DVD. It doesn't seem to be bootable.

Comment: Try again using http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows

Comment: personally i would go with rufus+usb stick.  tested and working

Comment: Thank you. I will try it again with a disk again and if that doesn't work I will use a USB.

Comment: Hold down the LEFT SHIFT KEY from cold boot and see if it gets you to the GRUB menu, where you can select which OS to boot. Cheers, Al